# SE Android app crashes on opening when logged in

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

If it's already logged in, the Android app v1.0.95 crashes every time I open it.

I can launch the app after using Settings to delete all of its data, but then it crashes when I log in.

This is on Android 8.1.0 on Pixel 2.

```
02-15 17:27:14.272 28616 28616 I Current : Activity Stopped: com.stackexchange.marvin.ui.LoadDataActivity
02-15 17:27:14.272 28616 28616 I Current : 2 activities remaining
02-15 17:27:14.275 28616 28616 I Current : Activity Stopped: com.stackexchange.marvin.ui.LaunchActivity
02-15 17:27:14.276 28616 28616 I Current : 1 activities remaining
02-15 17:27:14.342 28616 28616 W System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-15 17:27:14.342 28616 28616 W System.err:    at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:203)
02-15 17:27:14.342 28616 28616 W System.err:    at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.<init>(Arrays.java:3741)
02-15 17:27:14.342 28616 28616 W System.err:    at java.util.Arrays.asList(Arrays.java:3728)
02-15 17:27:14.342 28616 28616 W System.err:    at com.stackexchange.stacman.extensions.Feed.getCareersJobAds(Feed.java:47)
02-15 17:27:14.342 28616 28616 W System.err:    at com.stackexchange.marvin.ui.FeedFragment.parseFeed(FeedFragment.java:420)
02-15 17:27:14.342 28616 28616 W System.err:    at com.stackexchange.marvin.ui.FeedFragment.lambda$refreshEverything$2(FeedFragment.java:258)
02-15 17:27:14.342 28616 28616 W System.err:    at com.stackexchange.marvin.ui.FeedFragment.access$lambda$3(Unknown Source:0)
02-15 17:27:14.342 28616 28616 W System.err:    at com.stackexchange.marvin.ui.FeedFragment$$Lambda$5.call(Unknown Source:4)
02-15 17:27:14.342 28616 28616 W System.err:    at rx.Observable$32.onNext(Observable.java:7187)
02-15 17:27:14.342 28616 28616 W System.err:    at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber.onNext(SafeSubscriber.java:130)
02-15 17:27:14.342 28616 28616 W System.err:    at rx.internal.operators.NotificationLite.accept(NotificationLite.java:150)
02-15 17:27:14.342 28616 28616 W System.err:    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.pollQueue(OperatorObserveOn.java:189)
02-15 17:27:14.342 28616 28616 W System.err:    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.access$000(OperatorObserveOn.java:65)
02-15 17:27:14.342 28616 28616 W System.err:    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber$2.call(OperatorObserveOn.java:153)
02-15 17:27:14.342 28616 28616 W System.err:    at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:47)
02-15 17:27:14.342 28616 28616 W System.err:    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
02-15 17:27:14.342 28616 28616 W System.err:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-15 17:27:14.342 28616 28616 W System.err:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
02-15 17:27:14.342 28616 28616 W System.err:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
02-15 17:27:14.342 28616 28616 W System.err:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-15 17:27:14.342 28616 28616 W System.err:    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
02-15 17:27:14.342 28616 28616 W System.err:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/363447/6083675

Comment: If you've spent enough time browsing Java questions, you'll know that it's a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it :p

Answer (score 12):

Fixed as of a few minutes ago, sorry about not catching this before we released the back-end changes.

Copying from my MSO answer:

We made some changes to the backend that powered the feed to remove feed item types that are rarely seen and rarely clicked on but have upkeep for us on the back-end, and I had assumed the app was more resilient in how it handled the feed's data structure changing.

We've fixed it on the backend to replace the missing item types with empty lists of those item types, which fixes the NPE.

Comment: Thanks, @Kasra, that does seem to work. (For Laurel's comment I reflexively opened the notification only to see the app crash yet again. So when your notification came through, I was careful to not open it on mobile.)